# Switch DIV content using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Why is it not working after I added this code below? As you can see on snippet. Container #1 is not working when click. I've added title and content on it but it is not showing.

Is there anything that I can use instead of ***getElementsByTagName***?

```js
function showDiv(idInfo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('container' + idInfo).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#container1,
#container2,
#container3,
#container4 {
  display: none;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkDiv">
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('');return false">Home</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('1');return false">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('2');return false">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('3');return false">link 3</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('4');return false">link 4</a>
</div>

<div id="container">
  The container I want all content divs to load into... and by default, to show the first container content
</div>

<div id="divLinks">
  <div id="container1">Container #1
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Content:</div>
    <p>Whole bunch of text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    Container #2
    <p>Whole bunch of text 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container3">
    Container #3
    <p>Whole bunch of text 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container4">
    Container #4
    <p>Whole bunch of text 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `p` tag in your `#container1` says `Whole bunch of text 2`. Maybe that's why?

Comment: I have updated the snippet above. Still not working.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? When I click on `link n`, `container n` is shown.

Comment: There are another 2 divs on #container1. It doesn't show when I click on #container1.

Comment: Sorry, missed that! You can select the direct child using `querySelector` instead of targeting all `div`s

Comment: Do you mean document.querySelector('#containter1') instead of getElementsByTagName? I tried this but it's not working. Do you mind to show me how to do it in your way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target the direct children of `divLinks` only.

```js
function showDiv(idInfo) {
  const sel = document.querySelectorAll('#divLinks > div');
  
  sel.forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = item.id === `container${idInfo}` ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
#container1,
#container2,
#container3,
#container4 {
  display: none;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkDiv">
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('');return false">Home</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('1');return false">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('2');return false">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('3');return false">link 3</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('4');return false">link 4</a>
</div>

<div id="container">
  The container I want all content divs to load into... and by default, to show the first container content
</div>

<div id="divLinks">
  <div id="container1">Container #1
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Content:</div>
    <p>Whole bunch of text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    Container #2
    <p>Whole bunch of text 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container3">
    Container #3
    <p>Whole bunch of text 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="container4">
    Container #4
    <p>Whole bunch of text 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's working now! is it possible to highlight on the link on selected ones?

Comment: You can modify `showDiv` to also highlight/add a CSS class to the selected link.

Comment: Let's say I change it onclick from a tag to div, will it be the same way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, you just have to select the right tags. So in your case, the parent is now `linkDiv`.

Comment: Thanks and have a nice day ahead! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just only need to get Parent children not nested child.

> Just modify

`var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');`

> with

`sel = document.querySelector('#divLinks').children;`